# how to manipulate a value?

Tags: javascript, double

i have two double value..

one is 103.4738 and another is 103.4728 as they are only 0.001.

Is there a javascript function/way that i can do, to check against the value.. meaning if the value is +/- 0.0005 it would be a pass... and if not, it would be a fail?

Thanks~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to subtract and see the difference

```
var diff = number1 - number2;
if (Math.abs(diff) <= 0.0005) {
  // Pass
  ...
} else {
  // Fail
}
```

Note: Depending on the value chosen as the bar to meet (in this case 0.0005) you may run into subtle rounding errors because of the nature of floating point numbers.  If you're not familiar with this you may want to read the following

- http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: ohh ok.. thanks alot. did not know it will be just a few lines of code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var diff = Num1-Num2;
var status = (Math.abs(diff) <= 5*Math.pow(10,-5)) ? true : false;
```

Comment: sorry to ask, but, what does this line of code does? :)

5*Math.pow(10,-5)

Comment: 5*Math.pow(10,-5) = 0.0005. I did it to make it more general and if required u can change this constant in future